# Passing a controller variable to a view in Express/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

1st method

```
res.render('index',{people:people});
```

2nd method

```
res.locals.people = people;
res.render('index');
```

I saw there's 2 ways to pass variable to view, what's the different btw above method?

Answer (score 1):

I think they are the same for pass variable to render template, but there is a difference.
You can use `res.locals` to pass variable from serval middlewares.

**res.locals**

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is
>   identical to app.locals.
>
> This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as
>   the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  res.locals.authenticated = ! req.user.anonymous;
  next();
});
```

From this code, you pass `req.user` to next middleware.

Comment: so it's better to use res.locals? because it's more flexible?

Comment: I think if you want to render the template, i think `res.render('index',{people:people});` is a better way.